# number input always trigger change event

Tags: angular, events

I have a issue with Angulars change event on numeric input. It doesn't always trigger when i click the increment or decrament buttons, actualy it triggers once then it will trigger only after input losses hover.

My question is if there is some way to prevent this from happening or some replacement for change event.

some ground for testing:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2xj1a7)

Comment: `(input)` should be used

Comment: Can you clarify exact requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in coment's the best way of doing this is to use (input) event.

Like this:

`<input type="number" (input)="action()">`

Answer (score 1):

This is working as your expectation:

```
<input type="number" (mouseup)="changed()"/>
```

Comment: this doesn't work for up and down buttons in the input

Comment: Your question explains that you need code to be called when user use up/down button

Comment: It is woking on up/down button

Comment: sory i thougt you send me to use keyup

Comment: but unfortunetly it triggers when i click at the input the best practise is the (input) event as metioned by Maryannah under my question in comments.

Comment: Okay but you asked you need to triggered event when up/down button change. (input) is also the solution. You have to chose what you want